# No API version was specified Error

Tags: azure, zumo

I'm working on Azure Mobile Application, I downloaded Quick-start-Server side code and open it by using Visual Studio-2015. When I tried to browse it,Iam getting the issue like :"{"message":"No API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of '2.0.0'.  For more information and supported clients see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690568#2.0.0"}".

Can you give me solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the request which you are browsing is something like this

http://localhost/api/values/get

but you have to browse the URL by appending the ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0 something it should look like this

http://localhost/api/values/get?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0

And make sure both Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client and Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server are the latest version of the package.config.

This is because both mobile apps client and server are not compatible with each other so you need to send a special header value(ZUMO-API-VERSION) in the request message to make them in sync.